# Is it possible to modify data upon writing via Firebase Database Rules with ".validate" rule or alike?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I see that `.validate` rules can be used to check if certain data should be written depending on certain condition, such as:

```
".validate": "newData.isString()"
```

But is it possible to correct or modify the actual data? For example if we want a string to be saved always, it would be something like this:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() ? true : newData = ''; true"
```

If not, what would be the best alternative for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not the point of the Database rules. .validate will only check for the format.

If you want to modify the uploaded data, you have a nice example over here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Integrating Cloud Functions is fairly easy and does exactly the job what you want.